# D3 Transition to count up

Tags: animation, d3.js, data-visualization

Newbie here. I am building a D3 bar-chart, and was able to animate the bar height; however, I have a text field next to each bar that shows the values, I was unable to make the text count up as the bar height grows.

I am using the .text attribute with I think where the problem is:

```js
g.selectAll(".myText")
      .transition()
      .text(function(d){return (d.m6+"%")}) //code for counting from previous d.m6 value?
      .attr("transform", function(d) { ...code for moving text location...)
      .duration(700)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Transitioning plain text will just result in the end value being displayed on transition start (after any delay):

> For each selected element, sets the text content to the specified target value when the transition starts. .... Text is not interpolated by default because it is usually undesirable. ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_text)).

Here's an example of this at work:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");
  
var text = svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .text(1);
  
text.transition()
  .text(1000)
  .duration(1000)
  .delay(1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However, you can interpolate text, the most canonical method would be to use `transition.tween()` ([documentation](http://[transition.tween()](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_tween))). Though you could use .attrTween or even d3-timer. There are also a few other options out there but they are less straight forward.

A tween takes two arguments. The first argument is the name of the property being modified. The second argument is a tween value which returns a function of the form:

```
return function(t) { interpolator(t); })
```

Where `t` is a number between 0 and 1 representing the progress of the transition (0 = start, 1 = end), and interpolator is some function for interpolating a transition value for any point in the transition. With d3 this might be a d3-interpolator.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");
  
var text = svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .text(1);
  
text.transition()
  .tween("text", function() {
     var selection = d3.select(this);    // selection of node being transitioned
     var start = d3.select(this).text(); // start value prior to transition
     var end = 1000;                     // specified end value
     var interpolator = d3.interpolateNumber(start,end); // d3 interpolator

     return function(t) { selection.text(Math.round(interpolator(t))); };  // return value
     
  })
  .duration(10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I've just used rounding to keep the number formatted, otherwise the decimal points get pretty obnoxious. You could always apply some actual formatting.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you!!
The transition is part of a d3.selectAll, and the .tween already selects the "text" element, why do we need the d3.select(this).text()?

Also, shouldn't we simply return the interpolator? Why are we passing the "t"?

Comment: You can't return the interpolator (though it feels as though you *should*), we aren't returning a value to update the chosen field, we're running some function to update the selected element. This is the [canonical form](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_tween) of `.tween`. However, if we were using `.attrTween` we could pass the interpolator - but the text is not an attribute. Yes, I could have used `text.text()` - but this won't work if you have a selection of text that contains many elements (since `this` will be an individual element being transitioned).